# Angular form - img not binding to ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple angular form that I want to use to send an image to a remote server. I am binding the image `src` property to a photo pulled from device camera.

But when it's submitted, the image data is empty (`ng-model` is not binding to the img `src` attribute). I am having to separately add the image to the form object prior to submitting. Should i have to do that, or can I bind the image data properly to the form?

**HTML**

```
<form ng-submit="sendPost(post)">
  <img ng-src="{{imageURI}}" ng-model="$parent.post.image"/>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.post = {
   image: ''
}

$scope.imageURI = //this will be populated with a base64 encoded image pulled from the device camera roll

$scope.sendPost = function(post) {
  //i want post.image to have the image data that was sent to the <img> tag via camera when the form is submitted
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is too complicated, no need to bind `ngModel` as `<img>` is not an Angular directive, but a simple HTML tag.

**Option 1**

If you want your `<form>` to submit via Angular/AJAX, there's no need to have the `<img>`-tag in the form (or have a `<form>` at all), but I'll leave it in, as I am not sure if you want to show the image prior to submission or not.

**Option 2**

If you don't want to submit via Angular, you need an `<input type="hidden" ng-model="post.imageURI">`, but you also need the usual `action` attribute at the `<form>`

Back to option 1: just reduce your model to `$scope.post`, both for the HTML and the Angular code:

**HTML**

```
<form ng-submit="sendPost()">
  <img ng-src="{{post.imageURI}}"/>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.post = {}

$scope.post.imageURI = //this will be populated with a base64 encoded image pulled from the device camera roll

$scope.sendPost = function() {
       // need to check here if $scope.post.imageURI is populated
    $http.post(
    ...
    data: $scope.post,
    ....
    );
       //i want post.image to have the image data that was sent to the <img> tag via camera when the form is submitted
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand as <div>, <input>,  etc are also not directives but are bindable.  Yes I want to show the image ...that's the reason for the <img> tag. I am just adding it in the controller as you show, so I am accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML try change your ng-model from

```
<img ng-src="{{imageURI}}" ng-model="$parent.post.image />
```

to

```
<img ng-src="{{imageURI}}" ng-model="post.image" />
```

It should work.